# Python poetry install fails on typed-ast (1.5.4). How to overcome the obstacle and install the package?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-poetry, pyproject.toml, python-3.11

I tried to install the package using pip:

```bash
pip wheel --use-pep517 "typed-ast (==1.5.4)"
```

but it falls in the same place.

What's the general approach when you walk into such kind of problems?

I've found [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559), which seemed to be helpful, but it wasn't

```bash
(.venv) ➜  src git:(develop) ✗ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: poetry.lock is not consistent with pyproject.toml. You may be getting improper dependencies. Run `poetry lock [--no-update]` to fix it.

Package operations: 24 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing typed-ast (1.5.4): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
  
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
  copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast/tests
  copying ast3/tests/test_basics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast/tests
  running build_ext
  building '_ast27' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Custom
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Parser
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Python
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/tmp/tmpwhqt9erw/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
  ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      1 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  

  at ~/c/mrnet/mrnet_backend/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│ 
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│ 
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│ 
      154│             return path
      155│ 
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with typed-ast (1.5.4) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "typed-ast (==1.5.4)"'.

(.venv) ➜  src git:(develop) ✗ pip wheel --use-pep517 "typed-ast (==1.5.4)"
Collecting typed-ast==1.5.4
  Using cached typed_ast-1.5.4.tar.gz (252 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: typed-ast
  Building wheel for typed-ast (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for typed-ast (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast/tests
      copying ast3/tests/test_basics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/typed_ast/tests
      running build_ext
      building '_ast27' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Custom
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Parser
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Python
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/yevt/c/mrnet/mrnet_backend/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
      ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
          1 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
Failed to build typed-ast
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
(.venv) ➜  src git:(develop) ✗ pip wheel --use-pep517 "typed-ast (==1.5.4)"
```

- ubuntu 22.04
- gcc 11.3.0
- python 3.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you install python3.11-dev?

```
sudo apt install -y python3.11-dev
```

or packages for compiling

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3.11-dev
```

Comment: Installing python3.11-dev was enough. Could you explain why, please?